# How to set up a single product shop with woocommerce? Skipping the product archive

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, archives, single

I am looking for a solution to eliminate the shop page which is the product archive for a single product shop.

So visiting domain.com/shop should link to the single product page domain.com/shop/product-name

Is there a solution with the permalinks settings?

Thank you folks!

Answer (score 0):

Put domain.com/shop/product-name as a custom link in your menu of site. and make it as a home page so whenever someone clicks on  domain.com/shop, it will go to your one page product.

Comment: Thanks. But I have another page as landing page.
And besides that: as far as I know, I cant set a product as home page.